# ICMPv6 Header modification in Linux Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel

How do  I modify the Neighbor Solicitation/ Neighbor Advertisement  Message header with option filed added in Linux existing kernel and recompile it.

Comment: Will iptables not help?

Comment: I want to modify the ICMPv6 header add new options in header so that when it sends NS message to neighbor it send information added in option.